# Show options of selection from database based on parent selection

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have a form with 2 selection boxes, both of these boxes draw their options from my database through php.

The first one shows a list of books ordered by their ISBN like this:

`<ISBN> - <Book name>`

Now the second selection box will list all the editions that exist for the book selected in the previous selection (based on ISBN) and show each one of them with just the number of the edition.

What I do in this form is insert a specific copy of the selected book with the specific edition with its serial number in the database.

What I try to do is with the `onChange` to retrieve the ISBN selected from the first `select` and use it to show the options of the second selection.

I use the function `dropdown()` to display the book `select` and the `dropdownEdition()` for the edition select:

```
function dropdown($intIdField, $strNameField, $strTableName, $strOrderField, 
         $strNameOrdinal, $strMethod="asc") {
   echo "<select name=\"$strNameOrdinal\">\n";
   echo "<option value=\"NULL\">Select Value</option>\n";
   
   $strQuery = "select $intIdField, $strNameField
               from $strTableName
               order by $strOrderField $strMethod";

   $rsrcResult = mysql_query($strQuery);

   while($arrayRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsrcResult)) {
       $strA = $arrayRow["$intIdField"];
       $strB = $arrayRow["$intIdField"] . " - " . $arrayRow["$strNameField"];
       echo "<option value=\"$strA\">$strB</option>\n";
   }
   echo "</select>";
}

function dropdownEdition($intId1Field, $intId2Field, $strTableName, $strOrderField, 
         $strNameOrdinal, $strMethod="asc") {      
    
   echo "<select name=\"$strNameOrdinal\">\n";
   echo "<option value=\"NULL\">Select Value</option>\n";
   
   $strQuery = "SELECT $intId1Field, $intId2Field
               FROM $strTableName
               ORDER BY $strOrderField $strMethod";

   $rsrcResult = mysql_query($strQuery);

   while($arrayRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsrcResult)) {
       $strA = $arrayRow["$intId1Field"];
       echo "<option value=\"$strA\">$strA</option>\n";
   }

   echo "</select>";
}
```

What I basically want to do is pass the ISBN selected previously with the `onChange`, in the variable `$intId2Field` of the `dropdownEdition()`.

The problem with that is I have searched for tutorials but I can't understand anything because I have never worked with jQuery or Javascript or AJAX and I am a very novice web programmer. That is the reason for I am asking for some help here.

Here are how the 2 functions are called:

```
 <?php dropdown("book_ISBN", "book_title", "book", "book_ISBN", "book"); ?>

 <?php dropdownEdition("edition_no", "???????", "edition", "edition_no", "edition"); ?>`
```

The ???? are the book_ISBN because I don't know how to pass it in.

Here are how the tables are connected:

[image]

References -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've already figured this out, but you will need to make an asynchronous request to the server, passing the ISBN to a PHP script which will execute your mySQL query.

Your PHP script would return the mysql results, possibly as a JSON object which could then be parsed using JS and formatted as HTML.

Here is some code I chucked together to demonstrate.

HTML:

```
<select name="isbn-select" id="isbn-select">
  <option value="">Select an ISBN</option>
  <option value="isbn1">isbn1</option>
  <option value="isbn2">isbn2</option>
  <option value="isbn3">isbn3</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('#isbn-select').on('change', function() {
  isbn = $('#isbn-select').val();
  $.getJSON('get_editions.php',
  {
  isbn: isbn
  },
  function(data) {
    var editions = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
      editions.push('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
    });
    $('<select/>', {
      'id': 'editions-select',
      'name': 'editions-select',
      html: editions.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// Code to select editions from your database goes here....
// Your isbn can be accessed as $_GET['isbn']
$editions_arr = array('editon1', 'edition2', 'edition3');
echo json_encode($editions_arr);
?>
```

I have used jQuery's `getJSON` method to fetch a JSON object from `get_editions.php`. The results are then formatted as a `select` and appended to the HTML document. To keep things simple I am not doing any error checking or validation.

I hope this helps get you on the right track!

**EDIT:**

If you wish to return formatted HTML instead of a JSON object, here's how you can do that.

JS:

```
$('#isbn-select').on('change', function() {
  isbn = $('#isbn-select').val();
  $.get('get_editions.php',
  {
  isbn: isbn
  },
  function(data) {
    $('body').append(data);
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// Code to select editions from your database goes here....
// Your isbn can be accessed as $_GET['isbn']
$editions_html = '<select id="editions-select" name="editions-select">';
$editions_html .= '<option value="edition1">edition1</option>';
$editions_html .= '<option value="edition2">edition2</option>';
$editions_html .= '<option value="edition3">edition3</option>';
$editions_html .= '</select>';
echo $editions_html;
?>
```

You can read up on jQuery's AJAX functions here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Could you possibly explain a bit more how to implement this tin my code? It's just that I have no idea about JSON objects and I can't understand almost anything

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how you could return formatted HTML instead of JSON. However if you do plan do do much work sending data between the server and JS then it's worth investing the time to learn more about JSON.

Comment: What if I had a "GO" button next to the isbn form and after pressing it the selected ISBN would be passed in the edition form how would I go with that? Sorry for asking too much but I want to avoid jQuery because I have no idea how to use it...also I have no time to learn it because i started my finals

Comment: If you want to populate the second select (editions) without a page refresh then you have to load data via AJAX, and IMO the most efficient and simplest way to do that is with jQuery. You could do it with pure JavaScript, but if you don't know jQ then I assume you don't know JS either? In any case, you asked for an AJAX solution, and that's what I've given you - I don't think I can make it any simpler. Your only other option as I see it is to have two separate pages, one with the ISBN select and one with the editions select.

Comment: By the way - in your last comment you mentioned that you are starting your finals. Can I ask if this is a homework question?

Comment: I had about a month or 2 ago a similar assignment and when I finished the assignment I did it like you said with 2 separate pages and i didn't like the solution that much and since then i've been trying to find the way of having it in the same page just because I'm curious of how it is done

Comment: Well I don't think you'll find a solution that differs in substance to what I've done. The only way to query a database after a page has loaded, and without refreshing the page, is with JavaScript. If this is something you're interested in learning then I recommend investing the time in becoming familiar with jS/jQuery/AJAX. The snippets I've given you are 100% functional and should provide a solid starting point. Good luck.